# trying to redirect when a marker is clicked using gmaps4rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, callback, google-maps-markers, gmaps4rails

I'm having a issue using gmaps4rails, when I click on a marker nothing happens even though according to previous questions I've seen this should work.

controller

```
@json = User.all.to_gmaps4rails do |object|
    "\"link\": \"http://localhost:3000/users\""
end
```

and view

```
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
<% content_for :scripts do %>
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect_to(url) {
  window.location = url;
};
Gmaps4Rails.callback = function() { 
  function say_yo(arg) { return function(){alert('yo '+ arg + '!' );};};
    for (var i = 0; i <  Gmaps4Rails.markers.length; ++i) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps4Rails.markers[i].google_object, 'click', redirect_to(Gmaps4Rails.markers[i].link));
    }
}
</script>
```

Another issue is if in the for loop if google is the standard variable you are supposed to use or am I missing something as I've never seen or written a call to create a google variable I believe.

Addon: I know this is obtrusive javascript which is bad but I've never found a tutorial I could understand for unobtrusive javascript that worked so planning on making it unobtrusive sometime in the future.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my question is outdated now, the previous answer I found was from a older version that still needed to use javascript apparently, now to create an infobox you just need to look at the controller section of the wiki, and there are various features with markers as well.  It all works nicely and I haven't found a need to use javascript yet which is great.